# How to count the number of characters on each line with group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a customer table with an ID column and another customer name column.

```
------------------
|  table client  |
------------------
| id | name      |
------------------
| 1  | name nome |
| 2  | name two  |
| 3  | name three|
| 4  | name four |
| 5  | name five |
| 6  | name six  |
------------------
```

I need to create a query that counts by grouping the lines according to the number of characters in the string. In the table above the query should return the following:

quantity of characters: 3, Quanty of of records: 2

quantity of characters: 4, Quanty of of records: 3

quantity of characters: 5, Quanty of of records: 1

That is: two names with three characters, 3 names with four characters and 1 name with five characters.

does anyone know how I could do this query?

Comment: What name in your sample data has three characters?  I don't understand the results.

Comment: Incidentally, it would be hard to devise a more obscure example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to count the characters in a string along with the counts

```
create table t(id int, name varchar(50))

insert into t 
select 1,'nome' union all
select 2,'two' union all
select 3,'three' union all
select 4, 'four'

select length(name),count(*)
 from t
group by length(name)


+--------------+----------+
| length(name) | count(*) |
+--------------+----------+
|            3 |        1 |
|            4 |        2 |
|            5 |        1 |
+--------------+----------+
```

Here is a full example
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c738c8eb29c9b31b191f55ba8c7023a9

Comment: Note that length mishandles multi-byte characters

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph: you can use [`char_length()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) instead of `length()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had ti think my numbers where much higer, so i chekced again, hw you came to your 4 and 3

> ```
> CREATE TABLE client (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(10)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO client
>   (`id`, `name`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'nome'),
>   ('2', 'two'),
>   ('3', 'three'),
>   ('4', 'four'),
>   ('5', 'five'),
>   ('6', 'six');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(`name`),COUNT(*) FROM client GROUP BY CHAR_LENGTH(`name`) ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(`name`)
> ```
>
> ```
> CHAR_LENGTH(`name`) | COUNT(*)
> ------------------: | -------:
>                   3 |        2
>                   4 |        3
>                   5 |        1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1318c7d67419b83865fc0a501fd8d9b0)*

Comment: I'm just not a fan of handing out fish. Cui bono?

Comment: i thoughzt the counting was for `name nome` and in end effect he wamts `nome` mad teh funy thinkl i wrote a function that counts the individual letters in the hole string and those numbers also didn't fit